# Why won't this css maintain the width?

Tags: html, css, winjs

Note, I'm using angular.winjs 4.4.0 and winjs 4.4.3 to make this demo. But this is really about getting the right css to force the width as I declare it.

What I'm expecting is the width to be as I declare it and the text to wrap itself within the div. Instead, what I'm getting the text going straight across as if there's no width declared.

So I'm wondering if this CSS is correct.

HTML (with angular tags)

```
<div class="fullScreen">
    <div id="appHeader">
        <div>
            <win-back-button></win-back-button>
            <h2 class="win-h2">App Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <win-hub>
                <win-hub-section header="'Images'" is-header-static="'true'">
                    <div class="section1">
                        stvqqtertgwvcrqrgqwerywtwetbueyjehtrghcqewfqewx how
                        stvqqtertgwvcrqrgqwerywtwetbueyjehtrghcqewfqewx
                    </div>
                </win-hub-section>
                <win-hub-section header="'ListView'" is-header-static="'true'">
                    <div class="section2">
                        srtvwtrevwthvw cretgqcxtqryqreywtyuwtrjuvbeyjyetbjetyjeythvwrgwrcfg why
                        srtvwtrevwthvw cretgqcxtqryqreywtyuwtrjuvbeyjyetbjetyjeythvwrgwrcfg
                    </div>
                </win-hub-section>
                <win-hub-section header="'Video'" is-header-static="'true'">
                    <div ng-class="section3">
                        wetryvwrfgvwthertyjeybjbetrhwvrgqregcqgrwehrtejetyjkrbukrutyjbetrhvwergqcerfqrgwehtrjrytnkukrjbevthvwrqce maybe
                        wetryvwrfgvwthertyjeybjbetrhwvrgqregcqgrwehrtejetyjkrbukrutyjbetrhvwergqcerfqrgwehtrjrytnkukrjbevthvwrqce
                    </div>
                </win-hub-section>
                <win-hub-section header="'Form Controls'" is-header-static="'true'">
                    <div ng-class="section4">
                        srgtcvwerfgvwhertyjytrkn4tjbethvwgwqrefqewtewrcgrtehtverhjtyjbyjyhvw3rtg2q3ref134t26ytyveh654ub457j3thv2rg1cr14tf1q243tcx  3erx    23r34 hello
                        srgtcvwerfgvwhertyjytrkn4tjbethvwgwqrefqewtewrcgrtehtverhjtyjbyjyhvw3rtg2q3ref134t26ytyveh654ub457j3thv2rg1cr14tf1q243tcx  3erx    23r34
                    </div>
                </win-hub-section>
            </win-hub>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fullScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*width of each section*/
.win-hub-section .section1 {
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.win-hub-section .section2 {
    width: 194px; 
}

.win-hub-section .section3 {
    width: 100px;
}

.win-hub-section .section4 {
    width: 130px;
}
```

HTML (partial, raw as browser produces it)

```
<div class="ng-isolate-scope win-hub win-disposable win-hub-horizontal win-element-resize">
    <div class="win-hub-viewport" role="group" style="opacity: 1; -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapList(0px, 710px, 1635px, 3072px);" aria-label="Scrolling Container">
        <div class="win-hub-surface">
            <div class="win-hub-section win-disposable" ng-transclude="true">
                <div class="win-hub-section-header">
                    <button class="win-hub-section-header-tabstop" role="heading" type="button">
                        <div tabindex="-1" class="win-hub-section-header-wrapper">
                            <h2 class="win-type-subheader win-hub-section-header-content">Images</h2>
                            <span class="win-hub-section-header-chevron win-type-body">See more</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="win-hub-section-content">
                    <div class="section1 ng-scope">
                        stvqqtertgwvcrqrgqwerywtwetbueyjehtrghcqewfqewx how
                        stvqqtertgwvcrqrgqwerywtwetbueyjehtrghcqewfqewx
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have unbroken words (no spaces) like stvqqtertgwvcrqrgqwerywtwetbueyjehtrghcqewfqewx then CSS will not break the words by default, and will over flow its container if the width of the container is less than the width of the word

Comment: above is correct, but unless the text is inside a p tag it wont break it even if it does has spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to break a long string that has no spaces, then you have to define 'word-wrap: break-word;' CSS property for that element (along with the width), provided it's not an inline element (div, by default, is not)